# ServiceSTack: CSV file name

Tags: servicestack

Service Stack 3 - How can the filename for the attachment in ?format=csv be customized on a per response basis?

I have googled this, but the only article of interest suggested replacing the entire format provider, which seems very extreme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not extreme if you want customized behavior to replace the [CsvFormat](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Formats/CsvFormat.cs) which is only a few lines of code:

```
public class CsvFormat : IPlugin
{
    public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        //Register the 'text/csv' content-type and serializers (format is inferred from the last part of the content-type)
        appHost.ContentTypes.Register(MimeTypes.Csv,
            SerializeToStream, CsvSerializer.DeserializeFromStream);

        //Add a response filter to add a 'Content-Disposition' header so browsers treat it natively as a .csv file
        appHost.GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
        {
            if (req.ResponseContentType == MimeTypes.Csv)
            {
                res.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, $"attachment;filename={req.OperationName}.csv");
            }
        });
    }

    public void SerializeToStream(IRequest requestContext, object request, Stream stream)
    {
        CsvSerializer.SerializeToStream(request, stream);
    }
}
```

By default the filename returned will be the Request DTO Name, but you can change it to use whatever you want with your own custom CsvFormat which you can add by first removing the pre-registered CsvFormat then registering your own, e.g:

```
Plugins.RemoveAll(x => x is CsvFormat);

Plugins.Add(new MyCsvFormat());
```

Comment: Thanks, this puts me on track; I didn't realize the provider was a trivial shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the filename in a service method by setting the Request.OperationName. Like this:

```
    public object Any(RequestWithFilename request)
    {
        ...

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Filename))
            Request.OperationName = request.Filename;

        ...
    }
```